# Bug in Processor power management?

Tags: windows-10

I have an old laptop (Intel T2370) which was recently upgraded in place to Windows 10. After upgraded, the CPU utilization was consistently maxed out by three processes: System, Desktop Windows Manager, and, ta-dum, Task Manager. The total from these three do not add up to 99% but Task Manager kept showing 99%. As a result, the fan blows like a jet engine.

I went to `Power Options` and changed `Processor power management`, `Maximum processor state` when `Plugged in` from 100% to 99%.  Immediately, Task Manager shows big drop to around 30% average utilization.

I have another Dell laptop with an Intel i7-3612QM. It had the same jet-engine problem with high CPU utilization for no reason. I set the Maximum processor state to below 100% and the problem went away.  I then set it back to 100% and the problem didn't return.

Is there a bug somewhere?

Comment: I have no idea. But capture 2 traces of this (one with 100 and 1 with 99% setting). Install the WPT (part of the Win10 SDK: https://dev.windows.com/en-us/downloads/windows-10-sdk), run WPRUI.exe, select first level, CPU usage, power usage) and run 1 minute of the system activity for 100% setting and 1minute for 99% setting. Compress both ETL files + NGENPDB folder als a 7z/RAR file (to reduce the size), upload the 7z/RAR file to onedrive, share it and post the share link here. I'll try to take a look at it

Comment: Well, on the old laptop, I set Maximum processor state when Plugged in back to 100%.  CPU utilization still remains below 30%. If I do the recordings now, there would be no difference. I will collect the data if the CPU maxes out again. Thanks.

Comment: can you now reproduce this issue?

Answer (score 0):

When you lower the max CPU state to 99% you disable Intel turbo boost. This greatly reduces the TDP and thus fans may not spin as hard. Consequently, you may actually be getting better performance.